# Android 2.2 Default Intent

Tags: android

Hi
 What are the new/modified default in android 2.2 .I want to know 2.2 extra features over 2.1 also

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [sdk page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/), there is the changelogs in between platform version